# How do I return data with multiple numeric values?

Tags: sql

so far this is my query... I want to return values with min position and max volume. however... some keyword for corresponding url have multiple keyword with same position. I just want to return 1 result per url.. 
For example, my columns are

```
|URL          |keyword|Position| volume|
| www.ex.com  |example| 1      | 10.   |
| www.ex.com  | ex    | 1      | 20.   |
| www.ex.com  | lol   | 1      | 30.   |
| www.ex.com/h| hello | 4      | 40    |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which database you are using so I'll assume it's a modern one, with window functions:

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by URL order by position, volume desc) as rn
  from (
    -- your query here
  ) x
) y
where rn = 1
```